# Insert into multiple database doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-insert, ado

I would like to add a vehicle to my database with multiple fuel types selected in a listbox.

In my database I have tables `Vehicle`, `Fueltype` and an intermediate table `Fueltype_Vehicle`.

Adding a vehicle works (first SQL command).

The second one is not executed anymore. Here the id of the fueltype that is selected and the vehicleId should be added to the intermediate table. But this is not executed, no error is given either. it says that the vehicle has been added but in the database I see that nothing at all has been added to the intermediate table.

Can anyone help me?

```
public void AddVehicle(Vehicle v)
{
    int vehicleId;

    var fueltypes = v.getFueltypes();

    string sql = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Vehicle] (brand, model, chassisnumber, licenseplate, type, color, doors) VALUES (@brand, @model, @chassisnumber, @licenseplate, @type, @color, @doors) SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";

    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connString);
    SqlCommand command = new(sql, connection);

    try
    {
        connection.Open();                

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@brand", v.Brand);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@model", v.Model);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@chassisnumber", v.ChassisNumber);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@licenceplate", v.Licenseplate);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", v.Type);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Color", v.Color);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Doors", v.Doors);                

        vehicleId = Decimal.ToInt32((decimal)command.ExecuteScalar());

        foreach (var fueltype in fueltypes)
        {
            string sql2 = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Fueltype_Vehicle] (fueltypeId, vehicleId) VALUES (@fueltypeId, @vehicleId)";

            SqlCommand command2 = new(sql2, connection);

            command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fueltypeId", fueltype.Id);
            command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vehicleId", vehicleId);                  
            
            command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new VehicleException(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any exception?

Comment: No, it just insert into the vehicle table but nothin into the fueltype_vehicle table

Comment: is `fueltypes` empty?

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: `new(sql, connection);` and `new(sql2, connection);` ... new what?

Comment: `vehicleId = Decimal.ToInt32((decimal)command.ExecuteScalar());` ... why the cast to decimal and back to int?

Comment: Have you tried including `set nocount on; ` before your insert statements? The insert operation will return a rowcount of 1, but no result set, and could be confusing `ExecuteScalar`.